# Harmony - add property to object, or similar effect

Tags: c#, harmony

There's a class I can't edit directly with a method something like

```
BuildingSaveData {
    public override BuildingSaveData SaveTheThing(Building b){
       this.propOne = b.propOne;
       //etc etc
       return this;
    }

    public SerializableVector3 propOne;
}
```

And somewhere down the line it gets serialized and saved off for later.

Then in reverse

```
public override Building LoadTheThing(Building b){
    b.propOne = this.propOne;
    //etc etc
    return b;
}
```

I want to add a property to this object to get serialized/deserialized along with everything else.

I don't think it's possible to add a property at runtime to a class in C#, but I'm not that familiar with Harmony yet so it may have some magic for this I'm unaware of.

**My Attempt**

This is what I'm trying to do on the save:

```
[HarmonyPatch(typeof(BuildingSaveData))]
[HarmonyPatch(nameof(BuildingSaveData.SaveTheThing))]
public class BuildingSavePatch 
{
    static void Postfix(Building b, BuildingSaveData __result)
    {
        __result.localScale = b.transform.GetChild(0).localScale;
    }
}
```

But this throws the obvious error of "BuildingSaveData does not contain a definition for localScale"